# Is there a way to identify which formControl value changed?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Is there a way to identify which `formControl` had it's value updated when listening to changes in the `form`, and not on a certain control?

Code is something like this:

```js
myForm = fb.group( .... );
...
myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(changes=> ????? which control changed ????? );
```

Comment: You can use the .dirty (or .pristine) values of each input to determine if a user has used the UI to change the control value

Answer (score 0):

you can use dirty for find the changes in form control

```
    this.myForm['controls'].forEach((element, index) => {
     if (element.dirty) {
        // your code here
     }
   });
```

Comment: This code throws an error. ForEach doesnt work because the controls don't have indexes, they have keys. I made it work using  `Object.keys(this.myForm.controls).forEach((key: string) => { .... } ); `

Comment: yes this is just reference for you ,you can change it by your usage.